# libboost installation per apt-get - where are the files located? how do I link them in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, c++, boost

Im trying to install the boost libraries and entered
sudo apt-get libboost*
i managed to set the include paths and the header-only librarys are working.
when I try other libraries like regex I get an "reference not found" error
Where do I set the paths for the Linker and what path do I need to set?
(cant find the files on my file system)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use libboost in eclipse you also need the header files or libboost-something-dev.

Then in CDT project properties->Build->Settings->compiler->include path
Make sure you have the folder containing the headers(probably automatic if you install the via -dev packages and your compile toolchain is set up properly).

Then in CDT project properties->Build->Settings->linker->libraries
Add the library name like you would to your gcc -l line in the top part and the search path(might be automatic if you use the -dev package) in the bottom part.

click->Apply
click->OK
And it should build.

Just a note:  Using the global include and lib directories gets you automatic updates to components on apt-get update && apt-get upgrade + recompile.  I personally like to cherry pick the .h and .a/.o files I need and put the in a project specific ./include and ./lib subfolder within the project.